# Slowing down the displayed serial data in Python

Tags: python, serialization, gyroscope

Below is the python code to collect serial data from a gyro. The printed values are continuous real-time data. When I run the code, the data that is displayed from the serial port is very fast. I would like to get 10 Hz data (slow down the displaying values). Can someone please assist me with this? Thank you!!

```
import serial
import struct
#import csv
ser = serial.Serial("COM5",115200)
buffer = []
while 1:
        val = ser.read(1)
        if (val == '\x7e'):
            val = ser.read(1)
            if (val == '\x5D'):
                val = ser.read(18)
                data = struct.unpack(">HHhhhhlh",val)
                print data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `slow down the displaying values`, you mean drop extra values so they're only printing out at a max rate of 10Hz, then you just need to track the time every time you print a value.  The following is pretty crude, and won't give you exactly 10Hz (it will actually give you a max of 10 Hz).  You could track a longer history of times to get a frequency closer to 10Hz.

If you don't want to lose any values, then you're going to have to describe your problem better, since if your data is being generated faster than 10Hz and you're only going to print it out at 10Hz, at some point you're going to run out of memory buffering the data.

```
import serial
import struct
import time
#import csv
ser = serial.Serial("COM5",115200)
buffer = []
last_displayed = 0
while 1:
        val = ser.read(1)
        if (val == '\x7e'):
            val = ser.read(1)
            if (val == '\x5D'):
                val = ser.read(18)
                data = struct.unpack(">HHhhhhlh",val)
                cur_time = time.time()
                if cur_time - last_displayed >= .1:  # ~10Hz
                    print data
                    last_displayed = cur_time
```